How to enable read write operations on a logical replica on RDS?
I have a blue green deployment on AWS RDS Postgresql which is basically using logical replication of Postgresql. Whenever an insert takes place on table A on green env I would like to be inserted on tables A and B on green env.
For that case, I used a trigger that whenever is fired a function is called:
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER some_trigger
        BEFORE INSERT ON A
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE function insert_to_B ();

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_to_B ()
        RETURNS TRIGGER
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
        SET default_transaction_read_only = off
        AS $TRIG$
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN

            INSERT INTO public.B VALUES ( NEW.*);

            RETURN NEW;

        END IF;

    END

    $TRIG$;




The issue is that currently, rds allows you to modify default_transaction_read_only only on the session level.
This is causing the insert to fail with:
ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction
Is there a way to overcome this? Probably app could wrap this insert in a transaction block where transaction read write could be set. Is there another solution?

Am I understanding correctly, that this concerns the replica and you want to insert into B when an insert into A is received from the publishing side? If so, can you update the question, your text only contains table A which doesn't match the code.

Updated the text

The question is still quite unclear. The use-case doesn't mention anything about actual replication (all on green env) and we have no idea why the transaction is read_only in the first place. Anyhow, why change the default value when you can just SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE?
